# Can I scale a Windows Azure Shared Website to multiple instances?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Looking at the Windows Azure Websites portal, under the SCALE page, when SHARED option is selected, the instance count slider is visible. The slider does not move however.

I would like to use 2 instances of the shared website. I assume this should be possible since it is a paid service and I would simply be charged double. I don't need the full RESERVED option just yet.

Is this possible?

Comment: Update 2013-01-25: During some changes I just noticed that shared instance count for a north Europe site can now be changed up to 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible according to [the documentation](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/how-to-scale-websites/#howtochangescale) and this [intro video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VFIUxsuGopc). There are also [threads in the Azure Websites Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurewebsitespreview/thread/9dffff8d-ed04-4e42-9e81-7b6917f2c814) discussing this topic.
The management portal help also documents the **Shared Instance Count**.

Keep in mind that websites is still in preview so availability may vary and some constraints are not yet final.

I just tried and was unable to scale newly created shared websites at two different locations (the slider just stuck at 1).

**Update 2013-01-25**: During some changes I just noticed that shared instance count for a north Europe site can now be changed up to 6.